# Domain wide deletion of Temporary Internet Files in IE 7

Tags: domain, internet-explorer-7, files

What is the best way and how would you go about the domain wide deletion of Temporary Internet Files in IE 7 per machine per user?

It would be nice to be able to do this on demand but some kind of Group Policy solution would be good too.

Thanks!
Everett

Answer (score 1):

You could use a logon script served up by Group Policy with the script [here](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/scriptcenter/resources/qanda/nov04/hey1102.mspx)

Or a startup script with [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/19380/delete-temporary-files-from-batch-script-in-xp/19510#19510)