# script (search & delete temp files/folder) has got a failure

Tags: cache, batch-file, user-profile, files

I use this script to clean history, cookies and cache(Temporary Internet Files) for all users AND it should also clean the temp dir BUT there seems to be something wrong.

2 things get mixed up I think, the %temp% variable (= D:\TEMP in my environment) AND the users temp dir in the %userprofile%

```
:: Works on Win XP  -and-  on Win 7

@echo off

Set "RegKey=HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList"
set "regkey2=HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\shell folders"

call:getspecialfolders "Cache, History, Cookies"

For /f "tokens=*" %%? in (
 'Reg.exe QUERY "%RegKey%" ^|findstr /ric:"\S-1-5-21-[0-9]*-[0-9]*-[0-9]*-[0-9]*$"'
 ) do (
 For /f "tokens=2,*" %%A in (
 'Reg.exe QUERY "%%?" /v ProfileImagePath ^|find /i "ProfileImagePath"'
 ) do call:Go %%B
)

start ""/w "%windir%\system32\RunDll32.exe" InetCpl.cpl,ClearMyTracksByProcess 255

:end ***


goto:EOF
:Go
   call Set "Target=%*"
   If EXIST "%Target%" call:Clear "%Target%"
exit /b 0

:Clear
REM echo.&echo.%~1\%$$Cache%
   pushD "%~1\%$$Cache%" &&(
   rmdir /S /Q .
   popD)2>C:\test1_TEMP_IE.txt

REM echo.&echo.%~1\%$$History%\History.IE5
REM    pushD "%~1\%$$History%\History.IE5" &&(
REM    rmdir /S /Q .
REM    popD)2>C:\test1_History_IE.txt

REM echo.&echo.%~1\%$$History%
   pushD "%~1\%$$History%" &&(
   rmdir /S /Q .
   popD)2>C:\test1_History.txt

REM echo.&echo.%~1\%$$Cookies%
   pushD "%~1\%$$Cookies%" &&(
   rmdir /S /Q .
   popD)2>C:\test1_Cookies.txt

ECHO.&echo.%~1\%$$temp%
   pushD "%~1\%$$temp%" &&(
   rmdir /S /Q .
   popD)2>C:\test1_Temp.txt
exit /b 0

:getspecialfolders
   Set "FoldersToClear=%~1"

   For %%* in (%FoldersToClear%) Do (
     For /f "tokens=2,*" %%A in (
     'reg.exe query "%regkey2%" /v %%* ^|find /i "%%~*"'
     ) do Call:sf1 "%%~B" "%%~*"
   )
   Call:sf2 "%temp%" "temp" "%userprofile%"
exit /b 0

:sf1
   Call set "sf=%~1"
   Call set "$$%~2=%%sf:%userprofile%\=%%"
exit /b 0

:sf2
   Call set "sf=%~1"
   call Set "usr=%~dpns3"
   Call set "$$%~2=%%sf:%usr%\=%%"
exit /b 0
```

BUT somehow I can't get the last "temp part" to function so it cleans the %temp% (D:\Temp in my environment) and also to find all "temp dir's" in the %userprofile%.

**ie.** this for instance does work for %temp%:

```
PushD "%Temp%" && (
ATTRIB -S -H -R -A /D /S & (
For /f "Tokens=*" %%* in ('dir "%Temp%" /B') Do (
RD "%Temp%\%%*" /S /Q || Del /F /S /Q "%Temp%\%%*"))&PopD)2>c:\test0b_TEMP.txt
```

**and this ie.** works for the "user(s) temp":

```
::Set Search directory to "Documents and Settings" folder
(Set Target=%AllUsersProfile:~0,-10%)

title,Finding the Temp subfolders in %Target%&COLOR 9E

If EXIST "%Target%",(
  For /f "Tokens=*" %%* in ('dir "%Target%" /B') Do (
   cd/D "%target%\%%*\Local Settings\Temp" && (
   ATTRIB -S -H -R -A /D /S >nul & (
  For /f "Tokens=*" %%* in ('dir /B') Do (
   RD "%%*" /S /Q ||Del /F "%%*" )))>nul)
 )
```

I hope some one can help me out in fixing the script, I think it's in the :sf2 and/or in combination with the %temp% part, somehow 2 things get mixed-up ("users temp" en "environment temp").

Comment: possible related question: http://serverfault.com/questions/19380/delete-temporary-files-from-batch-script-in-xp

Comment: this is what I got/get with "my" script (nothing changed yet):                                                                     **C:\Documents and Settings\admin-lksvdd\D:\TEMP**

Comment: Script works when: Default windows temp = used. So windows default set back to: _%UserProfile%\Local Settings\Temp_ (for currentuser) **and** _%SystemRoot%\Temp_ (system variable). Now how to fix the script so it will still work when none windows defaults are used (i.e. D:\TEMP) ... That's when things go horribly wrong **:-(**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to bee a work-around:

instead of

```
ECHO.&echo.%~1\%$$temp%
   pushD "%~1\%$$temp%" &&(
   rmdir /S /Q .
   popD)2>C:\test1_Temp.tx
```

use

```
IF "%$$temp%"=="%$$temp:*:=%" (SET "tmppath=%~1\%$$temp%") ELSE SET "tmppath=%$$temp%"
ECHO.&echo.%tmppath%
   pushD "%tmppath%" &&(
   rmdir /S /Q .
   popD)2>C:\test1_Temp.txt
```

credits go out to: **Andriy M**